# jquery bounce accelerates automatically

Tags: jquery, bounce

I im not sure why my bounce effect is accelerating.

I have the effect on an image, with a setInterval. Everything starts perfectly, but suddenly the effect starts to accelerate automatically. I though it was a problem of the seconds in the interval and with the bouncing time parameter, but not correct.

I have also a suspicion, that the problem could start, when I change the tab or window.

Does any had the same problem or is there another way to emulate the bounce effect?

Here the snippet:

```
<div style="position:absolute; margin-left:675px; margin-top:50px; width:25px; height:25px;">
window.setInterval(function(){
 $(".show-awards-new-image").effect("bounce", { times:2, direction:'up', distance:25 },200);
},4000);
</div>
```

ty!

Comment: why is your javascript code inside a div ?????? i cant take your snippet serious

Comment: well you can use your imagination and understand that the code is part of a bigger code and that the other code is meaningless

Answer (score 0):

as you can see in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qW9r5/1/

there is no accelerate.

you can use the `.animate()` function from jquery (no UI needed) to simulate this bounce effect rather easy.

Comment: thanks ggzone, Im using inside the while loop a clearQueue() and stop() every 10 times, and then starting again: